# How can I create this module ('lab_utils_uni') in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 6>()
      3 import matplotlib as mpl
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 6 from lab_utils_uni import plt_intuition, plt_stationary, plt_update_onclick, soup_bowl
      7 #plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle')
      9 x_train = np.array([1.0, 2.0])           #(size in 1000 square feet)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lab_utils_uni'
```

How can I create this module in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify (with code) what lab_utils_uni is and where is it in relation to your current script directory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Recently I finished a Machine Learning course in which some codes were provided to help students get knowledge about machine learning. When I run this code in the course module it worked, but when I paste that into my Jupyter Notebook it doesn't work. Here is my code:

Comment: # NumPy, a popular library for scientific computing 
# Matplotlib, a popular library for plotting data
# local plotting routines in the lab_utils_uni.py file in the local directory

Comment: Sorry, I can't paste my code here in an appropriate format.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create it, You get it from Coursera:

```
lab files
```

from there download it and upload it into your personal jupyter notebook. Make sure to download all the files, especially `deeplearning.mplstyle`, `lab_utils_common.py`, `lab_utils_multi.py` and keep them in one folder.